# How to condition this problem involving Urns

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> There are two urns one with 6 blue objects an 4 yellow objects, and the other with 3 blue objects and 4 yellow objects. We choose an object at random.
>
> (1) If an object we select is yellow, what is the probability it came from the first urn?
>
> (2) Assume we put the yellow object from (1) back in the urn it was drawn from and then draw an object from the same urn. This object is also yellow. What is the probability we chose the first urn?

I have already determined that $$\mathbb{P}(\{\text{We drew from the first urn}\}| \{\text{The object was yellow}\})=\frac{1}{2}.$$

$$\mathbb{P}(\{\text{We drew from the first urn}\}| \{\text{The object was yellow}\})$$

We compute this using Bayes' theorem.

$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(\{\text{The object was yellow}\}|\{\text{We drew from the first urn}\})\mathbb{P}(\{\text{We drew from the first urn}\})}{\mathbb{P}\{\text{The object was yellow}\}}$$

Implicit in the question are the following probabilities:

$$\mathbb{P}(\{\text{The object was yellow}\})=\frac{8}{17}$$

$$ \mathbb{P}(\{\text{The object was yellow}\}|\{\text{We drew from the first urn}\})=\frac{4}{10}$$

$$\mathbb{P}(\{\text{We drew from the first urn}\})=\frac{10}{17}$$

Combining these results together, we have that

$$\mathbb{P}(\{\text{We drew from the first urn}\}| \{\text{The object was yellow}\})=\frac{\frac{4}{10}\frac{10}{17}}{\frac{8}{17}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Part $(b)$ looks like it is asking to compute $\mathbb{P}(\{\text{We drew the second object the first urn}\}| \{\text{the set of outcomes such that the first and second draws are from the same urn and both objects are yellow}\})$.

Is this the correct way to set up the question?

Comment: Can you share how you determined

$$\mathbb{P}(\{\text{We drew from the first urn}\}| \{\text{The object was yellow}\})=\frac{1}{2}?$$

Because it is more likely to draw a yellow object from the second urn/box/bin than to draw a yellow object from the first urn/box/bin.

Comment: @peterwhy Updated with this part with some noational differences

Comment: @peterwhy Wouldn't it be the same since we are conditioning on the outcome being yellow but both have the same number of yellow balls?

Comment: the word "box"="urn" ?

Comment: @MathFail fixed

Comment: On the line

$$\mathbb{P}(\{\text{We drew from the first urn}\})=\frac{10}{17}$$

It should be that you pick one of the two urns by random, each with $\frac 12$ probability. The content inside the urns should not change their probability of being picked.

Comment: Do we have a definition or elaboration of "We choose an object at random"? Do we pick an urn uniformly at random, and then pick an object uniformly at random from that urn? Or do we pick out of all $17$ objects uniformly at random?

Answer (score 2):

(1) Before drawing from one of the urns, the urn we are drawing from is chosen randomly with the same probability.

$$P(\text{Urn 1}) = P(\text{Urn 2}) = \frac 12$$

The probability of drawing a yellow object from the chosen urn is not $\frac 8{17}$, because the objects have different probability to be chosen depending on the urn they are in.

$$\begin{align*}
P(\text{Urn 1}\mid \text{1st yellow})
&= \frac{P(\text{Urn 1} \cap \text{1st yellow})}{P(\text{1st yellow})}\\
&= \frac{P(\text{Urn 1} \cap \text{1st yellow})}{P(\text{Urn 1} \cap \text{1st yellow}) + P(\text{Urn 2} \cap \text{1st yellow})}\\
&= \frac{\frac 12\cdot \frac 4{10}}{\frac 12\cdot \frac 4{10} + \frac 12\cdot \frac 47}\\
&= \frac{7}{17}
\end{align*}$$

---

(2) Here the observation is that we have drawn two yellow objects (with replacement) from the chosen urn. The question does not confirm or deny which urn we are drawing from, but is only asking for the probability given the observation.

This assumes that from a fixed urn, the probabilities of drawing yellow objects (with replacement) every time are identical and independent.

$$\begin{align*}
&\quad P(\text{Urn 1}\mid \text{1st yellow}\cap \text{2nd yellow})\\
&= \frac{P(\text{Urn 1} \cap \text{1st yellow}\cap \text{2nd yellow})}{P(\text{1st yellow}\cap \text{2nd yellow})}\\
&= \frac{P(\text{Urn 1} \cap \text{1st yellow}\cap \text{2nd yellow})}{P(\text{Urn 1}\cap \text{1st yellow}\cap \text{2nd yellow})+P(\text{Urn 2}\cap \text{1st yellow}\cap \text{2nd yellow})}\\
&= \frac{\frac12 \cdot \frac4{10}\cdot\frac4{10}}{\frac12 \cdot \frac4{10}\cdot\frac4{10}+\frac12 \cdot \frac47\cdot\frac47}\\
&= \frac{49}{149}
\end{align*}$$

Or alternatively, to reuse part (1) that $P(\text{Urn 1}\mid \text{1st yellow})=\frac{7}{17}$,

$$\begin{align*}
&\quad P(\text{Urn 1}\mid \text{1st yellow}\cap \text{2nd yellow})\\
&= \frac{P(\text{Urn 1} \cap \text{1st yellow}\cap \text{2nd yellow})}{P(\text{1st yellow}\cap \text{2nd yellow})}\\
&= \frac{P(\text{Urn 1} \cap \text{2nd yellow}\mid \text{1st yellow})}{P(\text{2nd yellow}\mid\text{1st yellow})}\\
&= \frac{P(\text{Urn 1} \cap \text{2nd yellow}\mid \text{1st yellow})}{P(\text{Urn 1}\cap \text{2nd yellow}\mid\text{1st yellow})+P(\text{Urn 2}\cap \text{2nd yellow}\mid\text{1st yellow})}\\
&= \frac{\frac 7{17}\cdot \frac 4{10}}{\frac 7{17}\cdot \frac 4{10} + \left(1-\frac 7{17}\right)\cdot \frac 47}\\
&= \frac{49}{149}
\end{align*}$$

The calculation formats of the two alternatives are actually both similar to part (1), but replacing either

1. in the first method, replacing the probability of the observation given each urn:
   $$P(\text{1st yellow}\mid\text{Urn }x)
   \longrightarrow P(\text{1st yellow}\cap\text{2nd yellow}\mid\text{Urn }x)$$
2. in the second method, replacing the prior probability of choosing each urn:
   $$P(\text{Urn }x)
   \longrightarrow P(\text{Urn }x\mid \text{1st yellow})$$

Comment: Why does this answer not require part 1? Also are you sure you can apply independence as you have done?

Comment: I applied independence only on
$$P(\text{2nd yellow}\mid\text{Urn 1} \cap \text{1st yellow}) = P(\text{2nd yellow}\mid\text{Urn 1}) = \frac4{10},$$
and the corresponding given Urn 2. Because the two draws from the urn with replacement are independent. One specific place that I definitely did *not* apply independence is that

$$P(\text{Urn 1} \cap \text{1st yellow}) = P(\text{Urn 1})P(\text{1st yellow}\mid \text{Urn 1}) = \frac 12 \cdot \frac 4{10} \ne P(\text{Urn 1})P(\text{1st yellow}),$$

and the corresponding given Urn 2.

Comment: @user2950916 I added a way to reuse part (1) in part (2). Both give the same answer, but reusing part (1) didn't happen to be my first thought yesterday.

Comment: What would be wrong with doing
$P(\{\text{First draw from first urn}\} \cap \{\text{Second draw from second urn}\}|\{\text{Both draws are yellow}\}).$


By the definition of conditional probability, we may re-write this statement as 
\small
$=P(\{\text{Second draw urn 1}\} |\{\text{First draw urn 1}\} \cap \{\text{Both yellow}\})P( \{\text{First draw urn 1}| \text{First draw yellow}\})$

of which the left term equals $\frac{4}{10}$ and the right half is the result of part $(a)$ giving an answer of $\frac{4}{10}*\frac{7}{17}=\frac{14}{85}$ My solution doesn't include a denominator term

Comment: @user2950916 First, you wrote
$$P(\{\text{First draw from first urn}\} \cap \{\text{Second draw from second urn}\}|\{\text{Both draws are yellow}\}).$$
But from the drawing procedure in the question, we "draw an object from the same urn" and didn't switch urns. So your probability must be $0$. I assume this is a typo, and assume you meant "Second draw from first urn".

Comment: @user2950916 Then you wrote$$=P(\{\text{Second draw urn 1}\}|\{\text{First draw urn 1}\}\cap\{\underline{\text{Both yellow}}\})P(\{\text{First draw urn 1}| \underline{\text{First draw yellow}}\})$$(underline mine) The given conditions here didn't match. To match and apply chain rule correctly, the second probability would be $P( \{\text{First draw urn 1}\mid \text{Both yellow}\})$, a probability that the question wants. And also from the drawing procedure in the question, we "draw an object from the same urn". So I didn't bother to distinguish the urns in each draw.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, each urn has equal a priori probability of $\frac12$ of being chosen

P(1st urn |yellow) $= \frac{(Urn\; 1\; \cap\;yellow)}{(Urn1\;\cap\; yellow) + (urn2\;\cap\; yellow)}\quad\quad= \dfrac{\frac12\frac4{10}}{\dfrac12(\frac4{10}+\frac 47)}=\dfrac7{17}$

For the second part, we are returning the yellow to the **same** urn from which drawn,

Thus P(drawn second time from urn $1) = \dfrac7{17}\dfrac4{10} = \dfrac{14}{85}$

If the first time, yellow was drawn from urn $2$,the probability of drawing second time from Urn $1$ is obviously $0$ zero, so it won't enter the calculations for second part

---

**NOTE**

The question isn't very clearly phrased. I have taken it that the two urns are placed in such a way that while drawing, we don't know whether we are drawing from urn 1 or urn 2.Else the second part would become meaningless.

Comment: Why wouldn't the denominator of the first part for the probability of being yellow be $8/18$?

Comment: @user2950916: From where do you get $8/18$ ?

Comment: i meant 8/17. There are 8 yellow out of 17 objects so the probability of picking a yellow is 8/17. Every element of the sample space is an outcome, and there are 17 possible outcome, 8 of which yield a yellow ball.

Comment: $(4+6)$ in urn $1+(4+3)$ in urn $2 = 17$, no ?

Comment: Where did the 1/2 come fromm your denominator? Wouldn't the denominator just be $P(yellow)=8/17$?

Comment: @user2950916 Each urn has a probability of half of being selected. When different urns have different **proportions**  of yellow, you can't just lump together numerators and denominators. Please revise the concept of weighted averages. It is very late here, good night.

Comment: but $P(\text{first urn }|\text{ yellow})=\frac{P(first urn \cap yellow)P(first urn)}{P(\text{yellow})}=\frac{\frac{4}{10}\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{8}{17}}$?

Comment: I see now thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding for part $(2)$, let $A$= "from $1$st urn | ball is yellow"

$$P(A)=P(A\cap \text{part(1) from 1st urn})+P(A\cap \text{part(1) from 2nd urn})$$

$$P(A\cap \text{part(1) from 1st urn})=P(A~|~ \text{part(1) from 1st urn})\cdot P(\text{part(1) from 1st urn})$$

$P(A\cap \text{part(1) from 2nd urn})=0$, because it says "we put the yellow object from (1) back in the urn it was drawn from and then draw an object **from the same urn**", so if the first time in part(1) you draw from the 2nd urn, then for part(2), you still draw from 2nd urn (**from the same urn**), so event $A$ cannot happen, so this part is zero.

Comment: What is the meaning of from "1st urn | ball is yellow"? Is this a set? I thought conditioning was defined as a mesaure in terms of two events

Comment: No meaning. I only use A to refer to those words for laziness. @user2950916

Comment: Does that mean we have two conditionings going on here? Is that possible to condition w.r.t. two events at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I think part.2 has two conditionings, if carefully read its description in part (2), it depends on the result in part(1) @user2950916

Comment: @MathFall Wouldn't it instead be three conditionings, we condition on the first draw being yellow, the second draw being yellow, and the first draw being in the first bin?

Comment: Since you have done the part (1), you can use the result in part (1) directly, so don't need to repeat that part I think.